# Should I ask actual motto or goal of our company from boss?

Tags: professionalism, internship

I work in a company as my internship for one year at this company almost all the staff did not accept me as in staff my boss only directly assigned me the task only and did not allowed me to attend their staffs meeting I understand that em not actually the part of their staff only here for training but if my boss tell me their actual motto or goal I can work better for the company so should I ask about to their goal or continue my work as they assigned me.THE actual goal will also help me in my internship.

Comment: moto means that if they tell me that what they want to achive actually in their company. we can say mission?

Comment: mention it in my answer properly sir if u don't mind sir @JoeStrazzere

Comment: What is your actual goal with this question? You seem to want to attend meetings that you are not invited to, but in you are asking about the "motto". The two are probably two different problems. Some companies may not even have an official motto or slogan.

Comment: moto means what their main achievment they only assigned me the task meeting is the example which i have mention to tell that i have no idea abut their goal .

Answer (score 3):

This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/228441). While it is always a good idea to have an idea of the bigger picture than the one little task you're currently working on, whether that's at the level of "sprint goal", "6 month plan" or "company vision for the next ten years", it most cases it doesn't really affect things very much, particularly for junior staff. So, yes - you could have asked, but it wouldn't have made much difference to the world because you almost certainly still wouldn't have been invited to the staff meetings.

It sounds to me like what you need to be doing is going to your boss and explaining that you think it would be helpful to your internship if you were invited to the staff meetings. You can then have a discussion with him about why you're not being invited.

Answer (score 3):

> should I asked actual motto or goal of our company from boss?

Yes.

You should ask your boss questions so that you understand the goals of the company.

More importantly, you should ask questions whenever it isn't clear what you should do, or when you need more information to complete your assigned tasks effectively.